# PHP Duplicate Username Prevention on Register Form

Tags: php, forms, duplicates

Trying to stop users from registering duplicate accounts but code doesn't seem to work, don't know what I am doing wrong,

var_dump count shows "string(1) "0"

```
        $query1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_email = :email OR user_name = :username";
        $stmt = $DBH->prepare($query1);
        $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username,':email' => $email));
        $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

        // var_dump($count);

        if ($count > 0) {
            $error = "Username or E-Mail in Use. Please try another.";
        }
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what in this particular case? You always get an error?

Comment: Well it just registers, it does not count the rows and bringing up the error @tadman

Comment: Drop the `COUNT()` it's always going to be "1".

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner This could match up to two rows if there's unique constraints on those two columns.

Comment: There's no code here that registers, nor that prevents registration so we can't say what's going wrong with code we can't see.

Comment: @Tadman what I want is to prevent the user from registering if they input a duplicate username already in the database, this is the code that handles that and it isn't working in the prevention

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Removed the count, same error

Comment: That's a very odd and inefficient way to solve the problem. You should already have at least a unique inspdex if not a primary based on username - go ahead and insert, then have your code check for a duplicate key error and handle it.

Comment: This is pretty clunky code. Try writing a function that given those two parameters returns true or false accordingly, *then* once you can test and verify that function is working use it in your other code. This code should do the job described here, but as for the rest of it, I have no idea, I can't see it.

Comment: Like @symcbean says, if you have `UNIQUE` constraints on these columns you can always insert and see if the record bounces. It's still nice to have independent functions for verifying one property at a time because then you can AJAX link these through from your registration form, one per field, not to mention it's more modular. YOLO PHP style where you just dump code in your page's `.php` file isn't always the best way to tackle problems.

Comment: Hey guys @tadman i did what you said and made a unique constraint, i guess it worked because it comes with an error message "DOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'dd@hotmail.com' for key 'user_email''" I was just wondering is there anyway I can make this look nicer?

Comment: That's the idea, but you should rescue that exception and handle it properly, not just dump it on the user. Check for "integrity constraint violation" specifically.

Comment: @tadman Hey, I checked around and the best I have is 
 `if (!$result) {
        echo "Enter a different value";
    }`

it still dumps the error message on the user which is not what I want ;( any tips?

Comment: Use a [try { } catch { }](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) block to prevent the error being displayed

Comment: Like @nick said, this is a case for `try` and `catch` to grab the exception should it occur.